Equally sizing child views within a stack view SwiftUI
I'm trying to create a view where I have Text views in an HStack with circular backgrounds where each child is sized based off of the largest child in the stack. The goal is to have all of the views have the same width and height, across all size categories.
I have an implementation that is 90% of the way there, but I'm hitting some very odd behavior when trying to set both the width and heigh of the views.
It's worth noting I cannot use .infinity for the width due to this view needing to have a fixed width. Additionally, I need to target iOS 13 with this, so any solution that involves newer APIs for iOS 14+ I cannot use.
Here is the code I have:
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Testview

struct Testview: View {
    // MARK: Internal

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            CircleView(number: "2", maxSize: maxSize)
            CircleView(number: "24", maxSize: maxSize)
            CircleView(number: "246", maxSize: maxSize)
        }
        .background(Color.orange)
        .onPreferenceChange(CircleSizePreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
            maxSize = value
        })
    }

    // MARK: Private

    @State private var maxSize: CGSize = .zero
}

#Preview {
    Testview()
        .environment(\.sizeCategory, .extraLarge)
}

// MARK: - CircleView

struct CircleView: View {
    // MARK: Lifecycle

    init(number: String?, maxSize: CGSize) {
        if
            let number,
            !number.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
            self.number = number
        } else {
            self.number = " " // To preserve the size since an empty string results in a default sized circle (16.0 pts)
        }

        self.maxSize = maxSize
    }

    // MARK: Internal

    var number: String
    var maxSize: CGSize

    var body: some View {
        Text(number)
            .padding(8.0)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: CircleSizePreferenceKey.self,
                            value: geometry.size
                        )
                }
            )
            .frame(width: maxSize.width)
            .background(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height)
                    .background(
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(.black.opacity(0.15), lineWidth: 1.5)
                    )
            )
    }
}

// MARK: - CircleSizePreferenceKey

private struct CircleSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        let newSize = nextValue()
        let maxSize = max(value.width, value.height, newSize.width, newSize.height)

        value = CGSize(width: maxSize, height: maxSize)
    }
}

The above implementation is working great for the width (see below):

The issue with this is the parent doesn't know how tall it needs to be, so the top and bottom of the circle views extend beyond the bounds of the parent.
As soon as I set the height for the frame in the CircleView, the circle views shrink down to 16 points.

I've debugged the sizing of the views, and with the above, when providing the width only, the maxSize comes back as (110.666, 110.666), but when providing the height, the size comes back as (16.0, 16.0).
Can someone help with this and let me know if there is anything I'm doing incorrectly here or if there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10056

Thanks, but I need to target iOS 13, so the newer stuff from iOS 16 isn't viable for my application.

Your existing code works if you change the .frame being applied to the Text in CircleView:
Text(number)
    .padding(8.0)
    .background(
        // ...
    )
    // .frame(width: maxSize.width)
    .frame(minWidth: maxSize.width, minHeight: maxSize.height) //  HERE
    .background(
        // ...
    )

However, you were asking if there is a better way to achieve what you're trying to achieve.
There is certainly another way, which does not require the use of a PreferenceKey. This is to use a hidden placeholder to define the footprint for a CircleView. Then show the CircleView as an overlay over the footprint.

The width of the footprint can be found by using a ZStack to superimpose all numbers over each other. The ZStack adopts the dimension of the largest number.
To make the height of the footprint the same as the width (in other words, to give a square form), a GeometryReader is used in the background of the ZStack. The width measured by the GeometryReader is applied as minHeight to the ZStack.
The frame of an overlay is the same as the view it is applied to. If you show a Circle in this frame, it will fill the frame.
The number itself can be shown as an overlay over the circle.

struct Testview: View {
    private let numbers = ["2", "24", "246"]
    @State private var maxSize: CGFloat = .zero

    private var footprint: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(Array(numbers.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, numberString in
                Text(numberString)
            }
        }
        .padding(8.0)
        .background(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color(white: 1, opacity: 0)
                    .onAppear { maxSize = proxy.size.width }
            }
        )
        .frame(minHeight: maxSize)
        .hidden()
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(Array(numbers.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, numberString in
                footprint
                    .overlay(
                        CircleView(number: numberString)
                    )
            }
        }
        .background(Color.orange)
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    let number: String

    init(number: String?) {
        if let number,
           !number.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
            self.number = number
        } else {
            self.number = " " // To preserve the size since an empty string results in a default sized circle (16.0 pts)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .stroke(.black.opacity(0.15), lineWidth: 1.5)
            .overlay(
                Text(number)
            )
    }
}


If it's not practical to build the footprint in this way then you could stick with the approach of passing maxSize to CircleView, but without needing to use a PreferenceKey:
struct Testview: View {
    @State private var maxSize: CGFloat = .zero

    private var sizeDetector: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color(white: 1, opacity: 0)
                .onAppear {
                    maxSize = max(maxSize, proxy.size.width)
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            CircleView(number: "2", maxSize: maxSize)
                .background(sizeDetector)
            CircleView(number: "24", maxSize: maxSize)
                .background(sizeDetector)
            CircleView(number: "246", maxSize: maxSize)
                .background(sizeDetector)
        }
        .background(Color.orange)
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    private let number: String
    private let maxSize: CGFloat

    init(number: String?, maxSize: CGFloat) {
        if let number,
           !number.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
            self.number = number
        } else {
            self.number = " " // To preserve the size since an empty string results in a default sized circle (16.0 pts)
        }
        self.maxSize = maxSize
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(number)
            .padding(8.0)
            .frame(minWidth: maxSize, minHeight: maxSize)
            .background(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .stroke(.black.opacity(0.15), lineWidth: 1.5)
            )
    }
}


Thank you. It didn't even occur to me to use minWidth and minHeight instead of just width and height. I'll look through your alternate approach as well and see if it works better for my application.
